# Cannot use JSON.parse on "var temp = {'1':...}"?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

For a v.simple piece of code:

```
   var temp = {"1":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing once"],"2":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing twice :)"]};

   console.log(JSON.parse(temp)); //error is here
```

var temp is the json_encoded data.. yet i get this error =/ what does it mean i got wrong?

Comment: `JSON.parse` takes a string as argument, while `temp` is an object.

Comment: I am not really sure how to describe this in a title.... anyway, `JSON.parse` is first converting the object (known as `temp`) to a string, which results in "[object ...]" or similar (it's parsing what is displayed when doing `console.log(temp.toString())`). It is this (non-JSON) string that is then attempted to be parsed, which is where the specific syntax error comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that that is not JSON. That is a Javascript object. (The syntax for JSON is derived from that of a Javascript object.) It does not need to be parsed into a Javascript object because it already is one.

Just do `console.log(temp)` and you'll see this.

The reason you get this strange message is that trying to do `JSON.parse` on an object makes Javascript first attempt to convert the object into a string. The string that results is unhelpful: `"[object Object]"`. `JSON.parse` attempts to parse this. It copes with `[` but falls down on the first `o`, since that is illegal JSON syntax.

Comment: Okay that fixed it though my loop is running 127 times for an object with only 2 unique keys =/

like for(var i in temp) is 107 loops =/

Comment: @Dave You should always use `hasOwnProperty` when doing a `for..in` loop to avoid looping through inherited properties.

Comment: @Dave If you want to discuss that, you should open another question and show all the relevant code (including the one that works oddly).

Comment: "You should always use `hasOwnProperty` when doing a `for..in`"... is far too broad a statement to make. You should use it when the situation warrants it, which is far from "always". There's no reason to suggest such broad use of these types of guards.

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to pass a string to JSON.parse. In your example, you're passing an object. You may be looking for JSON.stringify():

```
var temp = {"1":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing once"],"2":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing twice :)"]}
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.parse()` is expecting a string. You are passing it an object. If you change your declaration of `temp` so that it actually contains a string of JSON then your code should work:

```
var temp = '{"1":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing once"],"2":["2","1","0000-00-00 00:00:00","testing twice :)"]}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert something in a JSON object in two ways:

```
1. from a string you can use JSON.parse that is faster than eval: 

  JSON.parse ('{"key":"value"}');

2. from an object you can use JSON.stringify:

  JSON.stringify ({"key":"value"});
```

For further info:

[JSON Doc](http://www.json.org/js.html)